# Division by NULL in IBM DB2

Tags: sql, null, db2, division

In Oracle, any number divided by NULL returns NULL. I was wondering what is the case for DB2 Databases?
The whole point of it is to check whether the following expression behaves in the same way for Oracle and DB2:
SELECT a / NULLIF(b, 0) FROM some_table;
Say b=0, we would get a division by null.

Comment: I believe in any database a manipulation with Null will result in Null, that is ANSI SQL way since Null is considered as unknown and anthing you do on top of an unknown is still unknown.

Answer (score 1):

The NULLIF function returns the null value if the two arguments are equal; otherwise, it returns the value of the first argument.

> > -NULLIF(expression,expression)-------------------------------

The result of using NULLIF(e1,e2) is the same as using the CASE expression:

CASE WHEN e1=e2 THEN NULL ELSE e1 END
Copy

When e1=e2 evaluates to unknown because one or both arguments is null, CASE expressions consider the evaluation not true. In this case, NULLIF returns the value 
of the first argument.
[IBM DB2 docs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_nullif.html)

So for DB2 and oracle it works same way

Answer (score 0):

Db2 returns null when one of the operators in a math expression is null.  For example

```
values (3 / cast(null as integer)) will return null.
```

On the other hand, the definition of NULLID is equal to that in Oracle. If both arguments are equal, it will return null.